# Binding expression exception when clicking on TreeView top level (root) item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, treeview

I'm seeing the following binding expression being thrown from a TreeView control ONLY when I've clicked on any of the root items in the tree view - if I click on any other item I DO NOT see a binding expression until I click on a root Item then I see the binding exception all the time.

The binding expression path is missing leading, 'Asset' & 'Trade' are values of a Name property on the Node class, which is a hierarchical data structure, it has a child collection of type Node etc...

The items are bound to the TreeView using a ListCollectionView.

.Net 4.0 WPF app running on Win7.

The class bound to the TreeView is as follows:

```
internal class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
{        
    public string Id { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Node Parent { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Asset'
>   property not found on 'object' ''Node' (HashCode=-729436854)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=Asset; DataItem='Node' (HashCode=-729436854);
>   target element is 'TreeView' (Name='FieldTreeView'); target property
>   is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 :
>   BindingExpression path error: 'Trade' property not found on 'object'
>   ''Node' (HashCode=-729436854)'. BindingExpression:Path=Trade;
>   DataItem='Node' (HashCode=-729436854); target element is 'TreeView'
>   (Name='FieldTreeView'); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')

This is the XAML for the TreeView, it being used as part of a WPF user control:

```
 <TreeView Name="FieldTreeView"
           Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="0,15,0,0"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
           VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
           SelectedItemChanged="FieldTreeViewOnSelectedItemChanged">
     <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
         <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children, Mode=OneWay}">
             <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                     <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FieldMenu, Mode=OneWay}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Title"
                                  Visibility="{Binding Path=HasFieldMenu, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                         <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                             <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding}" />
                                <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                                         Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.Id, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}" />
                             </Style>
                         </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ContextMenu>
                 </Grid.ContextMenu>
             </Grid>
         </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
       </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
       <TreeView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </TreeView.ItemsPanel>
       <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="FilterTreeViewOnItemMouseDoubleClick" />
            </Style>
         </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
     </TreeView>
```

The code used to populate the Node classes is shown below:

```
private void InitialiseFields()
{
   _rootNode.RemoveAllChildren();
   foreach (var field in _fields.OrderBy(x => x.Id))
   {
      NodeHelper.TokenizeIntoNodes(field, field.Id.Split(Node.IdSeperator), _menuMediator, _rootNode);
   }

   _nodes = _rootNode.Children.Cast<Node>().ToArray();
   FieldTreeView.ItemsSource = _rootNode.Children;
}
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code.

Comment: BindingExpression path error: 'Asset' property not found on 'object' ''Node'. - Your top level doesnt have all those properties.

Comment: try reading the question

Comment: I dont need to read the question as long I see the error I know whats going on. System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Asset' property not found on 'object' ''Node' (HashCode=-729436854)'. BindingExpression:Path=Asset; DataItem='Node' (HashCode=-729436854); target element is 'TreeView' . That means the DataContext which is placed in TreeView doesnt have Asset property. The TreeView is the top most control.

Comment: the TreeView.ItemsSource is set to a collection of Node objects in the code behind, a Node class has a Children collection (of Node objects) which is bound using a HierarchicalDataTemplate. So explain exactly where the issue is because I don't see it...

Comment: You havent showed us where and how you using binding with asset property but you get an error where it says the asset property couldnt be found. There is no asset in your code. Just show us what you doing with asset and we will be able to help you further more.

Comment: There is NO Asset or Trade property, I'll add the bound class to the question

Comment: Thats impossible. Show us code behind. Just post everything.

Comment: lol - its not impossible...

Comment: Maybe you had them before and you removed them from class but you forgot them somewhere :) Let us see your complete code.

Comment: nope that is the code apart from the Menu properties bound in the XAML, Asset & Trade are values of the Name property

Comment: Just post more code that shows how you set and fill itemssource for the treeview.